# Why isn't this shared preference being persisted on screen rotation?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Order of calls according to logcat is onCreate, setViewValues, setStrikethroughFlag, (ROTATE), onCreate, setViewValues:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings;
Editor spEditor;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ....
   mSettings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", "")
   spEditor = mSettings.edit(); 
   setViewValues();
}

public void setViewValues() {
    boolean isStrikeThru = mSettings.getBoolean(STRIKETHROUGH, false);
    Log.d("TRACE", "setViewValues, strikethrough " + isStrikeThru);
}


public void setStrikethroughFlag() {
    spEditor.putBoolean(STRIKETHROUGH, true);
                    spEditor.commit();
```

}

The logcat says setStrikethroughFlag() is called.  Then I rotate the screen, onCreate and setViewValues are called.  In setViewValues, I thought it would recognize the saved value of STRIKETHROUGH, true.  But the logcat trace says the value of isStrikeThru is false.

Comment: I do know about it, and the logcat confirmed what I thought.  What I don't know is why the sharedpreference didnt get persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was using quotes around the key when storing my shared preference.  The keys didnt match so nothing was persisted, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From know i can see, that you creating local variable in your `onCreate()`
And in your `setViewValues()` you accessing your class field variable.
So i am not sure that you are calling `getSharedPreferences()` on your field variable.
The same is about your `spEditor`. Fix this and try one more time.

If this will not help you, give as the rest of your code.

UPDATE

Try this `mSettings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: sorry, the SharedPreferences and Editor variables are class variables, I just reproduced them wrong in the OP.

Comment: Are you calling this inside Fragment or Activity?
I didn't find method in documentation getSharedPreferences(String, String);
See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the setViewValues() from the Constructor. In Screen orientation change, the oncreate of the activity will gets called again and resets your values.